# "ng build" in Angular

Tags: angular, npm, package

when I launch "ng build" in my project, there are these errors:

`ERROR in ../../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/index.d.ts(1,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/src/jwt.interceptor.d.ts(1,70): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'.
../../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/src/jwt.interceptor.d.ts(3,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/internal/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/src/jwtoptions.token.d.ts(1,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/accordion/accordion-group.component.d.ts(1,49):
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/accordion/accordion.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/alert/alert.component.d.ts(1,57): error TS2307:
Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/alert/alert.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/buttons/button-checkbox.directive.d.ts(1,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/buttons/button-checkbox.directive.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/buttons/button-radio-group.directive.d.ts(1,45): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/buttons/button-radio-group.directive.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/buttons/button-radio.directive.d.ts(1,76): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/buttons/button-radio.directive.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/buttons/buttons.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.component.d.ts(17,49): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/carousel/slide.component.d.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/collapse/collapse.directive.d.ts(1,53): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/collapse/collapse.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/component-loader/bs-component-ref.class.d.ts(1,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/component-loader/component-loader.class.d.ts(1,197): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/component-loader/component-loader.factory.d.ts(1,117): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/component-loader/content-ref.class.d.ts(5,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/base/bs-datepicker-container.d.ts(3,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker-inline.component.d.ts(1,116): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker-inline.component.d.ts(3,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker-input.directive.d.ts(1,58): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker-input.directive.d.ts(2,84): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.component.d.ts(1,116):
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.component.d.ts(3,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-daterangepicker-input.directive.d.ts(1,58): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-daterangepicker-input.directive.d.ts(2,84): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-daterangepicker.component.d.ts(1,116): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-daterangepicker.component.d.ts(3,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-locale.service.d.ts(1,45): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-inner.component.d.ts(1,64): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.component.d.ts(1,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.component.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/daypicker.component.d.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/monthpicker.component.d.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/reducer/bs-datepicker.effects.d.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-datepicker-container.component.d.ts(1,49): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-datepicker-container.component.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-datepicker-day-decorator.directive.d.ts(1,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-datepicker-inline-container.component.d.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-datepicker-navigation-view.component.d.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-daterangepicker-container.component.d.ts(1,49): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-daterangepicker-container.component.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-days-calendar-view.component.d.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-months-calendar-view.component.d.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-years-calendar-view.component.d.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/yearpicker.component.d.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/bs-dropdown-container.component.d.ts(1,69): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/bs-dropdown-menu.directive.d.ts(1,47):
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/bs-dropdown-toggle.directive.d.ts(1,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/bs-dropdown.directive.d.ts(1,90): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/bs-dropdown.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/bs-dropdown.state.d.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/mini-ngrx/state.class.d.ts(5,45): error TS2307:
Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/mini-ngrx/store.class.d.ts(4,48): error TS2307:
Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal.service.d.ts(1,75): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-backdrop.component.d.ts(1,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-container.component.d.ts(1,58): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal.directive.d.ts(1,104): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/pagination/pager.component.d.ts(1,79): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/pagination/pager.component.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/pagination/pagination.component.d.ts(1,79): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/pagination/pagination.component.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/pagination/pagination.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/popover/popover.directive.d.ts(1,103): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/popover/popover.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/positioning/positioning.service.d.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/progressbar/bar.component.d.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/progressbar/progressbar.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/rating/rating.component.d.ts(1,70): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/rating/rating.component.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/rating/rating.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/sortable/draggable-item.service.d.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/sortable/sortable.component.d.ts(1,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/sortable/sortable.component.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/sortable/sortable.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/tabs/ng-transclude.directive.d.ts(1,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/tabs/tab-heading.directive.d.ts(1,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/tabs/tab.directive.d.ts(1,85): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/tabs/tabs.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/tabs/tabset.component.d.ts(1,38): error TS2307:
Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/models/index.d.ts(1,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/models/index.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms/src/directives/control_value_accessor'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/models/index.d.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/src/type'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.component.d.ts(1,86): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.component.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.component.d.ts(7,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip-container.component.d.ts(1,31):
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.directive.d.ts(1,122): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.directive.d.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/utils/triggers.d.ts(5,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.`

Why do I have these errors?

Comment: Please, add to your answer the package.json info

Comment: Package.json file:

Comment: Try to delete `node_module` and `package.lock.json` file then run `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are in your project folder:
2. I assume you have looked at the [Angular quick start guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) and already run:

   `npm install -g @angular/cli`
3. If you downloaded an existing zipped up project without all the dependent libraries, then run

   `npm install`

   - Effectively it will create entries in the **node_modules** folder,
   - per your **package.json** within your project folder.
   - More can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm).
4. Run your `ng build`. More info [here](https://angular.io/cli/build)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: go ahead and delete the node_modules folder to make sure you get a clean install too

Answer (score 0):

Package.json file:

{
  "name": "pwa-spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.13.1",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}